# How do I assign a UNC identification to a WiFi router harddisk - in Windows 10?

Tags: hard-drive, wireless-networking, router, nas, unc

I have a router (TP-Link Archer C8, at 192.168.nn.1) with a 2GB harddisk in a USB 3.0 port. According to TP-Link the "Network/Media Server Name:" is TP-LINK_99999X (exemplary IP address and Device name).

Accessing the HDD works fine via \\192.168.nn.1\volume1\Directory in Windows explorer, but in the light of this thread https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/adding-a-mapped-network-drive-to-the-office-2010/ef12d2c6-4b55-42fe-b28c-527d8da6d6fb I need to refer to the drive via a UNC address.

First try was simply keying \\TP-LINK_99999X\volume1\Directory in WinExplorer, but alas - that did not work.

So what then?

Comment: Your current DNS server cannot resolve this name. Add proper record into your local %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS file (`192.168.nn.1 TP-LINK_99999X`), then use this name. Or you may try `nslookup 192.168.nn.1` - if TP-Link is your current DNS server it is possible that it assigns some predefined name for self, and you will see it.

Comment: Thanks Akina - your reply was spot on!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `\\192.168.nn.1\volume1` **is** a UNC path already (any `\\` address is a UNC address in Windows). The page never said anything that it has to have a device _name_.